# ViewSet and Router in rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Had a problem with rest framework:
building api with a viewset and router.

I want api to serialize the user's posts by url like that: 
/api/users/*user id*/posts/*page*, 
but router can`t stand it. 
It suggest me that regexp in patterns:

`^api/ ^ ^users/posts\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-posts']`

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

     @list_route()
     def posts(self, page):
         user = self.get_object()
         post_set = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
         paginator = Paginator(post_set, 16)
         serializer = PostSerializer(paginator.page(page), many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```

Have any ideas how to compel this work correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `/` after `posts` in your URL

Comment: Oh maybe i shoud try @detail_route

Comment: I mean in this: `^users/posts.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$` I think it should be this: `^users/posts/(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$`

Comment: @Cory, No, i just used the wrong decorator so it didn`t stand that I'm going to get the posts of particular user

Comment: here's some changes:
 `@detail_route()`, after it goes
    `def posts(self, request, pk)`.
Now it displays all user's post, but pagination doesn`t work. And inspite of it, router asks me for pk (never used in code)

Comment: pk is user id field

Comment: Try making this: `^users/posts.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$` look like this: `^users/posts.(?P<pk>[a-z0-9]+)/?$`

Answer (score 1):

views:

```
@detail_route()
def posts(self, request, pk, page):
    user = self.get_object()
    post_set = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
    paginator = Paginator(post_set, 16)
    serializer = PostSerializer(paginator.page(page), many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
user_posts = views.UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'posts'
})

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\w+)/posts/(?P<page>[0-9]+)', user_posts),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @detail_route()
    def posts(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object()
        post_set = Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
        paginator = Paginator(post_set, 16)
        page= request.query_params.get('page', 1)
        serializer = PostSerializer(paginator.page(page), many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
router.register('user', UserViewSet)
```